# Storing res/drawable images elsewhere Android?

Tags: android, drawable

I have several image files that i have in the res/drawable folder in my project. I'm using android 3.2. I've declared the images appropriately for the Action Bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/ports_page"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_program"
      android:title="@string/main1"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
<item android:id="@+id/listportingreds"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_list"
      android:title="@string/listportingred"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
```

ic_program.png and ic_list.png are both in the res/drawable folder. These are DIFFERENT LOOKING icons. The problem is both images are displayed as if they are both ic_program. If i double click the images in eclipse, they open appropriately, but on my app both images look exactly the same. I've even taken out ic_program, and copied ic_list and renamed the copy to ic_program and they still look like the original ic_program in the app.

Is it possible this other image is cached somewhere? Maybe in the file explore of the DDMS? I can't seem to find it. This seems like such a stupid thing but I can't figure out where to get it.

Comment: Neither works. Also, whenever someone opens the project on another computer for the first time, an image which used to have capital letter in it (which isn't allowed) will continue to have capital letters even though the file is locally named correctly. The app will change the file's name on the local machine to be the old incorrect name with capital letters. I have no idea where this data is being stored.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import them using Eclipse?  If you just added them using the file system you need to refresh your project so Eclipse sees them as part of the project.   If that's not the case then trying Luksporg and Macarse's suggestions might help.

Comment: No I dragged the files into the folder on my computer using windows explorer.

Comment: Tha might be the issue.  Refresh your project (right click project -> Refresh).  Once Eclipse recognizes the files as part of the project the Android plugin will kick in and regenerate your resource ID's

Comment: I've definitely refreshed before as I have the project in Dropbox and coding on multiple machines.